# Defining myApp and reusing it in controller in service

Tags: angularjs

I am getting javascript run time error

> myApp is undefined

for my angular service. Don't know what wrong im doing here..

This is how i defined my app.js

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute', 'motorControllers', 'motorDetailsController', 'motorServices', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.select', 'ngResource',]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/motors', {
            templateUrl: 'View/motorList.html',
            controller: 'motorController'
        }).
        when('/motors/:Id', {
            templateUrl: 'View/motorDetails.html',
            controller: 'motorDetailsController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/motors'
        });
  }]);
```

This is how i am creating/calling `myApp` in controller.

**Controller**

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('motorController', function ($scope, motorService) {

 //////
}
```

This is how i am trying use myApp in my service. but it gives error `myApp is undefined.`

**Service:**

```
myApp.service('motorService', ['$http', function ($http) {
//////
}
```

and this is how i declared it in my html

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

Looking forward for some help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that the error is in the controller's declaration, because you're defining the app 'myApp' twice.

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('motorController', function ($scope, motorService) {

 //////
}
```

should be

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('motorController', function ($scope, motorService) {

 //////
}
```

Edit
@simbada

It's up to you. You can separate them in different modules.

```
(function(angular){
        angular
            .module('myApp', ['myApp.Controllers']);

        angular
            .module('myApp.Services', [])
            .service('mySrv', function($http){
                function _get(){
                    return $http.get('url');
                }

                return {
                    get: _get
                }
            });

        angular
            .module('myApp.Controllers', ['myApp.Services'])
            .controller('myCtrl', function($scope, mySrv){
                $scope.var = 'Hello';
            });
    })(angular);
```

Comment: In this case get error "0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."

Comment: I got the reason for above error i mentioned. I was not loading app.js in my head tag of html. Another point, Do i need to inject controllers, service when defining myApp in app.js?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('motorController', function ($sc...
```

whitout [ ] brackets.

also see how you declare your service:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
'ngRoute', 'motorControllers', 'motorDetailsController', 'motorServices', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.select', 'ngResource']);
```

when your service is 'motorService'

Your service should be:

```
myApp = angular.module('motorServices');
myApp.service('motorService', ['$http', function ($http) {
```

//////
}

Comment: But i am getting 'myApp is undefined' error for my service.

Comment: you declared it as 'motorServices' when it is 'motorService'

Comment: i spotted this as well.. However, after correcting it i am still getting myApp is undefined.

Comment: in your app dependencies you are including 'motorControllers', why? is that a module you want to include?

Comment: I am not sure whether to include it or not. Its just another controller. Do i need to inject all controllers when defined app inside app.js?

Comment: you don't need to include it as it is a controller. Please remove an try again. Also remove 'motorDetailsController'.

Comment: It didn't work. Even i removed all controllers dependency injection from app.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97640/discussion-between-simbada-and-jax).

Answer (score 0):

You have passed comma in dependancy after `ngResource` just remove that it'll work fine.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute', 'motorControllers', 'motorDetailsController', 'motorServices', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.select', 'ngResource']);
```

Comment: Even i removed , after ngResource , it still says myApp is undefined in motorService.js.